# keras model.fit with validation data - which batch_size is used to evaluate the validation data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to validate my model with validation data inside

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size= 50, epochs=1,validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
```

Now, I want to train with batch_size=50. My validation data x_test is like of length of 1000. 
As I can read from the doc the validation data is used after each epoch to evaluate. So I assume the model.evaluate method is used? But what batch size is used?

My validation data is greater then the batch_size in the fit method.

How is this handled?

What are the result if just the training batch_size is used but validation data is larger? Is val_acc averaged over each batch?

I want to validate on all my data in one batch.

Comment: Yes, basically it will run `evaluate()` on the entire validation data. So you can see the loss and metrics value on the validation data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or you have more questions?

Comment: So If I understand you, the evaluation of the validation data inside the fit() method does not use the batch_size in the fit method?

Comment: Sorry, I was misinformed. The `batch_size` parameter in `model.fit` is used for both training and validation. Confirmation from the man himself :)
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6217

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keras uses the same `batch_size` parameter for both training and validation in `model.fit()`. See discussion [here](http://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6217).

If you intend to do evaluate on the entire validation data, you can maybe write a callback function and run `model.evaluate()` on the entire validation data after every epoch.

Comment: But you said: "Yes, basically it will run evaluate() on the entire validation data."


So theentire data set not just of size batchsize...

Comment: Yes. I said that. I was mistaken. I stand corrected now.

Comment: Ok so you propose a callback with model.evaluate(batch_size=I want)?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the easiest way to do it.